# Survival probability up to time $n$ in a branching process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations

Let $\{Z_n : n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ be a Galton-Watson branching process with time-homogeneous offspring distribution
$$\mathbb P(Z_{n,j} = 0) = 1-p = 1 - \mathbb P(Z_{n,j}=2), $$
where $0<p<1$. That is, $Z_0 = 1$ and
$$Z_n = \sum_{j=1}^{Z_{n-1}}Z_{n,j}$$
for $n\geqslant 1$. Let 
$$T=\inf\{n : Z_n=0\} $$
be the extinction time of the process. I want to find
$$t_n := \mathbb P(T>n), $$
i.e. the probability that the process survives up to time $n$. I found the following recurrence:

$$t_{n+1} = p(2t_n - t_n^2)$$
(with $t_0=1$) from this mathoverflow question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87199/branching-process-survival-probability

I checked the recurrence for small values of $n$, and confirmed that $t:=\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n$ satisfies
$$ t = p(2t - t^2),$$
both in the case where $t=0$ $\left(p\leqslant\frac12\right)$ and where $t=2-\frac1p$ $\left(p>\frac12\right)$. So I'm fairly confident this recurrence is valid. However, I have no idea how to solve it.

For context, this problem comes from *Adventures in Stochastic Processes* by Sidney Resnick:

[image]
From @Did's comment, it appears to be intractable to find a closed form for $\mathbb P(T>n)$. I find it curious that the question would be asked were it not, though.

Comment: There is no hope to get a closed formula for $t_n$, valid for each finite $n$, since this would be equivalent to an explicit solution of Mandelbrot style recursions $z\to z^2+c$. Additionally, to have such formulas would be of little practical interest.

Comment: That's interesting, as I found this problem in a textbook (Adventures in Stochastic Processes by Resnick). I'll add a screenshot of the original problem.

Comment: @Math1000 I've found a limited solution, have you made any headway?

Comment: I will take a look at it. Currently recovering from some medical issues so I'm not at peak mental capacity at the moment. Thank you though.

Comment: I believe @Did is right that there is no closed formula, but if you'd be interested in an approximation, in the continuous-time process the distribution of the extinction time has a simple form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the first generation in the branching process: either (1) we have $0$ offspring or (2) $2$ offsprings. Suppose $t_n$ is known. We would like to compute $t_{n+1}$, the probability that $T > n+1$. In order to have $T > n+1$, the first generation has to have $2$ offsprings, say $A$ and $B$. Now one of those two offsprings has to have $>n$ generations (think of two branching processes starting with $A$ and $B$ respectively). Therefore $$t_{n+1}=p\operatorname{Pr}\{A \text{ or }B \text{ (or both) has more than }n\text{ generations of offsprings}\} = p(2t_n-t_n^2).$$

In order to solve the recurrence, one may take advantage of $P(s) = q + ps^2$. Note that $$1-t_{n+1} = p(1-t_n)^2 + (1-p) = P(1-t_n).$$ Therefore $1-t_n = P^{(n)}(0)$ and so $t_n = 1-P^{(n)}(0)$.

Comment: I agree with this analysis, but how do we actually find a closed form for $t_n$?

Comment: I see. I thought you were asking for how one can get the recurrence. So you are after the closed for $t_n$, right?

Comment: Well, I did state in the original post "So I'm fairly confident this recurrence is valid. However, I have no idea how to solve it." But your answer is still helpful, as it confirms that the recurrence is indeed valid.

Comment: I see. I will let you know if I can say something about the recurrence.

Comment: I have updated my answer and it gives a formula for $t_n$.

Comment: Okay, not feeling well today (had a panic attack earlier), so when I am up to it, I will take a look and perhaps accept the answer.

Comment: Sure thing. Take care.

Comment: I've checked your work, and it makes sense. Thanks; this type of argument is exactly what I would have expected, just had some trouble coming up with it. To confirm - by $P^{(n)}(0)$ you mean functional iteration, right? So e.g. $P^{(2)}(0) = P(P(0))$.

Comment: Yes, I meant function compositions for $n$ times.

Comment: Thanks! Enjoy the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

For p approaching 1, there is a solution, and I'll post a proof later, at least this will get the ball rolling.
For p=1 the recurrence relation solves to $$t_n =1-e^{c*2^{n}}$$
For p=2, certainly not applicable to this case, the recurrence relation solves to $$t_n=1-\cos(c2^n)$$

**Proof**

The original recurrence relation is given by
$$t_{n+1}=p(2t_n-{t_n}^2)$$
I'll prove the first solution. For $p=1$ assume that the first equation is a solution for a number n. Substitute the solution into the relation.
$$1-e^{2c2^n}=2-2e^{c2^n}-(1-e^{c2^n})^2$$
Expand and simplify

$$1-e^{2c2^n}=2-2e^{c2^n}-1+2e^{c2^n}-e^{2c2^n}=1-e^{2c2^n}$$
The second solution is proved in much the same way, you'd just need to know some trig identities.

**Suggestions**
Use a computer for most of the calculations and do interpolation between the points. If you feel adventurous, find a derivation for the $p=1$ solution, and perform perturbation analysis, you may or may not get a convergent solution. I'll repost if I get anything interesting.

Comment: I did mention in the problem that $0<p<1$. Sorry if you didn't see that ;)

Comment: I mean, if $p=1$ then the problem is trivial, as $T=\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, well at least this can show qualitative behavior