# Solving nonlinear first-order difference equation $ d_m = p_0 + p_1d_{m-1} + p_2(d_{m-1})^2 $ (extinction problem)

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations

The steady-state equilibrium is $ d^* = \frac{1-p_1-\sqrt{(p_1-1)^2-4p_0p_2}}{2p_2} $. Based on a plot, I guessed the solution $ d_m = d^*(1-e^{-\alpha m}) $, which is pretty close but not correct. What other method can I use to solve this?

Context: This is to calculate the extinction probability of a branching process at each step, as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process#Example_of_extinction_problem.

Comment: I asked a similar question a few months ago. It is essentially the same, except that $p_1=0$. Hopefully it helps: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157670/survival-probability-up-to-time-n-in-a-branching-process

Comment: Quote: "There is no hope to get a closed formula for [the extinction probability after some given number n of generations], valid for each finite n, since this would be equivalent to an explicit solution of Mandelbrot style recursions z→z^2+c. Additionally, to have such formulas would be of little practical interest."